# How to get timestamp with milliseconds while retrieving from SQL Server?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

In a SQL Server database timestamps are added with milliseconds. But while retrieving, milliseconds are not begin returned, i.e. if the timestamp is `2012-04-23 15:03:35.345 PM`, when being retrieved, I get only `2012-04-23 15:03:35.000 PM`. I used the following code for retrieving the data:

```
query = "Select * from database";
_cmd = new SqlCommand(query, _con);

SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(_cmd);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);

foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
    string str = Convert.ToDateTime(dr[0].ToString()).ToString("yyyy-MM-ddhh:mm:ss.fff");
    dt[0] = str;
}
```

How can I get the milliseconds also?

Answer (score 3):

`dr[0]` is probably already a DateTime and converting it to string and back to DateTime won't do any good. I suppose you need to cast it:

```
string str = ((DateTime)dr[0]).ToString("yyyy-MM-ddhh:mm:ss.fff");
```

Use debugger to check the type of an expression by selecting entire expression (or just interesting part, in your case `dr[0]`), right click on selection and choose `QuickWatch'. Last column in the list is Type.